# Weka - Adding a unique identifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, identifier

I am running a logistic regression using Weka on a set of values with unique identifiers. I would like to run my historical data as the training data. In that case, I don't care about which values get classified into which categories. Once that is done, I would like to run my current data as the test data and I need to keep track of which values get classified into which categories. How can I maintain the unique identifiers for each category but not get them included as a variable in the regression?

Comment: I don't really see the problem. If you have information about instances that is irrelevant to the classification problem, then just don't feed them to the model, but keep them separate.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. I am using the GUI and I don't see how to keep the instance identifiers out of the model but have them reported with the prediction results.

Comment: You may have to do some programming, then (but don't take my word for it, I've never used the Weka GUI).